# Firebase Cloud Functions V2: A user creation trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud functions V2 with Node.js (not Typescript) and I need user creation trigger. In [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) I've found something, but it doesn't work. By the link I also can see the following hint there:

> Cloud Functions for Firebase (2nd gen) **does not provide** support for
> the events and triggers described in this guide.

Auth triggers doesn't work anymore for V2 cloud functions? If so, what is an alternative for this functionality? Below my code and deploy error:

```
const {functions} = require("firebase-functions");
initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

exports.authUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate({region: "europe-west1"}, (user) => {
  const userEmail = user.email;
  const userId = user.uid;
  return db.collection("users").doc(userId).update({createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), email: userEmail});
});
```

Deploy error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')`

Comment: The part of the docs that you didn't quote here say that you can deploy them as v1 functions that live alongside your v2 functions.  Just use the v1 syntax for now as if there was no v2 to worry about yet.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok how can I do that?

Comment: @DougStevenson currently I have the issue with my authUserCreated: `"TypeError: handler is not a function
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/cloud-functions.js:79:23)"`

Comment: If you have an additional problem with the new code you have, please post that separately. There should be enough information in the question that someone could use to copy and run it themselves to observe the new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `require` statement is wrong.  It should be:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Comment: Note: Firebase auth callbacks should be declared as V1 functions (I don't know why)

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko What do you mean? we got the same error and the callbacks are the same as the docs, however still we got the same error as you